# How to add label dynamically in tab control in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I was trying to output the results that have been found out to a label in a tab control. But it does not display them at all. Would someone please take a look at my code and tell me what I did wrong ? Thank you.

```
private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int indexResult = 0;
    string title, id;
    double price;
    string a = txtSearch.Text;

    if (Xbox360.HaveGame(a, ref indexResult))
    {
        title = Xbox360.GetTitle()[indexResult];
        Results.SetTitle(title);
        id = Xbox360.GetId()[indexResult];
        Results.SetId(id);
        price = Xbox360.GetPrice()[indexResult];
        Results.SetPrice(price);
    }

    if (Ps3.HaveGame(a, ref indexResult))
    {
        title = Ps3.GetTitle()[indexResult];
        Results.SetTitle(title);
        id = Ps3.GetId()[indexResult];
        Results.SetId(id);
        price = Ps3.GetPrice()[indexResult];
        Results.SetPrice(price);
    }

    if (Wii.HaveGame(a, ref indexResult))
    {
        title = Wii.GetTitle()[indexResult];
        Results.SetTitle(title);
        id = Wii.GetId()[indexResult];
        Results.SetId(id);
        price = Wii.GetPrice()[indexResult];
        Results.SetPrice(price);
    }

    // Basically I am going to output the result from the array Results, however, 
    // here I just want to output a sample string 
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Label resultLabel = new Label();
        resultLabel.Location = new Point(10, 7);
        resultLabel.Text = "output is here";
        this.Controls.Add(resultLabel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also consider to use heritage for Wii, Ps3 and Xbox class, then you can do:

```
foreach (GenericType console in consoleList)
{

    if (console.HaveGame(a, ref indexResult))
    {
        title = console.GetTitle()[indexResult];
        Results.SetTitle(title);
        id = console.GetId()[indexResult];
        Results.SetId(id);
        price = console.GetPrice()[indexResult];
        Results.SetPrice(price);
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah, I was trying to, except that we have not learned how to do inheritance yet :( Thanks for your tip.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding them to the TabPage you want to display them on:

```
this.TabControl1.TabPages[0].Controls.Add(resultLabel);
```

Comment: when you do tabpages[], does the subscript start as 0 or 1 ?

Comment: so, it starts as 0, yeah, and it works. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: @user2383193 indexes start at zero.  You can reference the tabpage by the TabPage name, too, or just reference the TabPage directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
 foreach (TabPage tab in myTabControl.TabPages)
 {
     Label lbl = new Label();
     lbl.Text = tab.Text;
     tab.Controls.Add(lbl);
 }
```